# Array result into an array

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to put the results of an array into a new Object array but cant seem to work out how.

I first create a chessboard array that is 10*10 and put the word hello into all the elements.

I then create a loop to go through all the elements to create a 10*10 matrix of what my array holds, in my case "hello". The output is called result1

I now want to put all the elements of result1 into an Object array called rowData[][]. The array of this will go into into a Jtable

```
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

String [][] chessboard = new String[10][10];
for (int row = 0;row<=9;row++){
    for (int col = 0; col <=9; col++){
        chessboard[row][col] = "hello";
    }
}

String result1 = "";
for (int row1 = 0;row1<=9;row1++){
    for (int col2 = 0; col2 <=9; col2++){
        result1 += chessboard[row1][col2];
    }
    result1 += "\r\n";
}
System.out.format(result1);

Object rowData[][] = {the result1 into each element of the new Object array};
```

Comment: You can just pass `result1`...

Comment: I don't get it. It seems like you are creating rowData to be identical to chessboard

Comment: JTable table = new JTable(result1, columnNames); i tried this but it doesnt seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the `String` array as it is -- no need for a new `Object[][]`:

```
JTable table = new JTable(chessboard, columnNames);
```

An array of strings is also an array of `Object`s. See [this relevant article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance) for covariance in Java arrays.

Comment: oh right, i see i would pass the whole chessboard array. Im a newbie to Java so many thanks for this. I didnt know "An array of strings is also an array of Objects"